# Trouble on state FIN_WAIT_1

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

recently i've got some port holding on **FIN_WAIT_1** state till two days later. The target port is used by one server process ever and client connect to the server process through this port.

The situation is we stopped the server process, and obviously some client is still connecting with the server at that moment. From my understanding, the server process sends a FIN package to client and waiting for the ACK package back. Unfortunately, that ACK package seems not like coming to server side till two days later.

my question is there any config like timeout to **FIN_WAIT_1** status. i walked through the internet searching but found nothing there. Please help tell me if you have any experience with this.

BTW, the server process has already gone while the FIN_WAIT_1 happening to the port.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Search google for "FIN_WAIT_1 timeout linux", should get you to http://serverfault.com/questions/7689/how-do-i-get-rid-of-sockets-in-fin-wait1-state which seems the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `FIN_WAIT_1` state is waiting for the peer to `ACK` the `FIN` that this end has just sent. That outgoing `FIN` is subject to all the normal TCP retry and timeout processing, so if the other end has completely disappeared and never responds, TCP should time out the connection and reset it as a matter of course. That's why you couldn't find a specific `FIN_WAIT_1` timeout: there isn't one, just the normal TCP write timers.

All that should have happened within ten minutes or so.

If the state persists and it causes other problems I don't think you don't have much option but to reboot.

Comment: it's really terrible for me having no other options but only to reboot since the state persist issue happens very often recently, so badddd....:-(      you just said the `FIN` is subject to all normal TCP retry and timeout. if so, is there any way to config the whole TCP timeout? and if i can do so, the `FIN` should be timeout due to previous setting? Right? But, if we can config the whole TCP timeout, then why the `FIN` state can persist? Please forgive me if my question is stupid, but i just dont understand now.  thanks a million with tax  @EJP

Comment: @wing2ofsky Sorry, I don't understand it either, at least why it has persisted for two days.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's the same ports stuck in FIN_WAIT? It could be due to a load balancer or NAT device that is dropping the connections after an inactivity timeout and silently discarding any further packets, which is the default behavior on some devices.